# Loop over all keys in array and obtain key name (column name) and key value

Tags: php, arrays

```
var_dump( $resultArray );
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'fname' => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'a' (length=1)
      'lname' => string 'z' (length=1)
      2 => string 'z' (length=1)
```

How do I loop over  $resultArray[0] to obtain key VALUES (column names) and Corresponding values for that key (instead of manually hardcoding `echo $resultArray[0]['id'];` etc.

Result should be:

```
KEYID: 0, KEY_VALUE: id, VALUE: 1
KEYID: 1, KEY_VALUE: fname, VALUE: a
KEYID: 2, KEY_VALUE: lname, VALUE: z
```

Comment: `foreach($array as $key => $value)`?

Comment: how do you get the name of that key? ID or FNAME or LNAME? `$value` is the same as  `$resultArray[n]` - but I still need to get the column names and corresponding values for those columns

Comment: the `$key` will contain the key. In this case `id, 0, fname, 1, lname, 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this,... I have not testet it so I cannot garantee it is working but the approach should be correct:

```
foreach ($resultArray as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
       echo('KEYID: ' .$key . ', KEY_VALUE: ' . $subKey . ' VALUE: ' .$subValue. "\n");
   }
}
```